# Mobile File Upload with Progress Bar on iOS7 Safari?

Tags: html, mobile, file-upload, progress-bar, mobile-safari

**How can I do file upload on iOS7 with Progress Bar?**

I have done file upload with a standard html form which works fine but I could not figure out how to implement a working progress bar on iOS7 Safari.